# Example of a $1$-categorical statement that really doesn't hold $\infty$-categorically

Tags: logic, category-theory, higher-category-theory

In many introductions to $\infty$-category theory (in the sense of Lurie and Joyal, so quasicategories), it is explained that many (if not most) $1$-categorical statements have analogues in $\infty$-categories that are true, although the  proof is often (if not always) more complicated.

I was wondering what kind of exceptions there were to this rule, if any :

> Is there a $1$-categorical statement that has no known analogue in $\infty$-category theory which is conjectured/proved to be true ? Or better yet, is there a $1$-categorical statement where we have strong evidence that there *could not* be a valid $\infty$-analogue ?

("strong evidence" could mean anything from counterexamples to the naive analogues to good heuristic reasons why an analogue *shouldn't* hold)

If there is no known example of this kind, this leads me to a second question :

> Is there any work on trying to automatize the process of going from $1$-CT to $\infty$-CT, e.g. a "translation theorem" that would say something along the lines of "if a statement $P$ [add technical hypotheses] holds in CT, then statement $f(P)$ holds in $\infty$-CT" where $f$ would be some explicit way of transforming a $1$-CT statement to an $\infty$-CT statement ?

(of course, as always with quasicategories, $\infty$-category here actually means $(\infty,1)$-category)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a somewhat vague example, "There is a natural useful concept of elementary topos" has been having some trouble. Shulman has conjectured a definition but things are quite tricky, as the 1-categorical notion of elementary topos is finitary, and that's one of its key desiderata, but any sort of $\infty$-topos seems to inherently require "infinite" objects such as the loop space $\mathbb{Z}$ of the circle. It is also difficult to understand what a finitary notion of $\infty$-equivalence relation should be, as this is pretty well understood in Grothendieck toposes to be about the geometric realization of simplicial objects. All this apparent inherent infinitary behavior is a significant obstacle for homotopy type theory's efforts to, in one interpretation, give an internal language for $\infty$-toposes interpretable on a computer.

A more concrete statement that is specifically known to be false: "Every Grothendieck topos is of the form 'sheaves on some site.'" The $\infty$-toposes which are sheaves on a site are, for instance, hypercomplete, a property with explicit counterexamples among general $\infty$-toposes.

For a more elementary counterexample, the formula expressing any colimit as a coequalizer does not hold in an $\infty$-category. However, it is true that any $\infty$-category admitting coproducts and pushouts is cocomplete; one must, however, perform an infinite (there it is again!) iterative construction to build a general colimit from these.

I don't really have anything to say on the closing question, except that I see no reason to think there should be such an automatic process. There are various efforts to express as much $\infty$-category theory in terms of ordinary category theory as possible, such as the program of Riehl and Verity and a part of the theory of derivators, but this isn't quite what you're asking.

Comment: Well given the counterexamples you gave, the closing question is not important (it was only in case no example was known). I like the sheaves example and the colimit example better than the first one, but that's a question of personal taste; thank you !

Comment: What's the definition of "Grothendieck topos" if not "sheaves on some site"?

Comment: @OscarCunningham In both 1- and $\infty$-settings, there are many characterizations. Simpler than sheaves on a site is that a Grothendieck topos is a left exact localization of a presheaf category. The analogous definition works for $\infty$-toposes, at least if one also assumes the right adjoint to the localization is accessible. There are also Giraud theorems in both cases giving more direct axiomatizations.

Comment: This is an old answer but to avoid some confusion I think it should say "hypersheaves" instead of "sheaves" since to my knowledge it remains an open question whether every $\infty$-topos can be written as the sheaf category of some $\infty$-site.